# Blank screen between two pages on IE 11

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-11

I am working on an enterprise application developed on MVC, JQuery and while moving between pages , we are regularly seeing a blank screen i.e. the HTML takes time to render however, the same is not seen on Chrome browser.

on heavy pages, the blank screen appears for 4-5 seconds and then the actual pages comes up. Again, the same behavior is not seen on chrome, even these heavy pages are loaded quickly without an intermittent display of blank screen

Please let me know if there is a setting in IE or in code that should be included to ensure quicker rendering of HTML on IE.

Thanks in Advance... !

Answer (score 0):

Blow tips might help you

1. validate pages with W3C standards.
2. Check any closing tag is missing.
3. Optimize the content if its to heavy to load, in chrome go to network select "all" option and reload page check loading time.
4. add preloader image remove it on window onload() method.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried this but nothing concrete came out. I wanted to understand the difference in behavior of IE vs Chrome especially why a blank screen comes up ... Probably it is because of difference in rendering of HTML . is there a setting in IE or a piece of code that will help IE render the HTML faster ? Thanks agian

Comment: Abhishek, even i faced this problem in IE many time, check if you have any video tag if yes remove the video tag and check.

Optimize all the images ie reduce the image size below 1mb

Try this lets see...

Answer (score 0):

Try to load site contents in the background for better performance in Internet Explorer.

You can follow steps below to enable that option in Internet Explorer.

(1) Go to **Tools** in Internet Explorer.

(2) Click on **Internet Options**.

(3) Select **Advanced** tab.

(4) Find an option called **Load sites and content in the background to optimize performance** and checked it.

[image]

Again try to make a test with your site in Internet Explorer 11.

if still issue persist than you may need to check your site and try to take some steps to make it lightweight to improve its performance in IE 11.